# Using different push-constants in different shader stages

Tags: glsl, shader, vulkan

I have a vertex shader with a push-constant block containing one float:

```
layout(push_constant) uniform pushConstants {
    float test1;
} u_pushConstants;
```

And a fragment shader with another push-constant block with a different float value:

```
layout(push_constant) uniform pushConstants {
    float test2;
} u_pushConstants;
```

*test1* and *test2* are supposed to be different.

The push-constant ranges for the pipeline layout are defined like this:

```
std::array<vk::PushConstantRange,2> ranges = {
    vk::PushConstantRange{
        vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eVertex,
        0,
        sizeof(float)
    },
    vk::PushConstantRange{
        vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eFragment,
        sizeof(float), // Push-constant range offset (Start after vertex push constants)
        sizeof(float)
    }
};
```

The actual constants are then pushed during rendering like this:

```
std::array<float,1> constants = {123.f};
commandBufferDraw.pushConstants(
    pipelineLayout,
    vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eVertex,
    0,
    sizeof(float),
    constants.data()
);
std::array<float,1> constants = {456.f};
commandBufferDraw.pushConstants(
    pipelineLayout,
    vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eFragment,
    sizeof(float), // Offset in bytes
    sizeof(float),
    constants.data()
);
```

However, when checking the values inside the shaders, both have the value 123.
It seems that the offsets are completely ignored. Am I using them incorrectly?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your pipeline layout, you stated that your vertex shader would access the range of data from [0, 4) bytes in the push constant range. You stated that your fragment shader would access the range of data from [4, 8) in the push constant range.

But your shaders tell a different story.

```
layout(push_constant) uniform pushConstants {
    float test2;
} u_pushConstants;
```

This definition very clearly says that the push constant range starts uses [0, 4). But you told Vulkan it uses [4, 8). Which should Vulkan believe: your shader, or your pipeline layout?

A general rule of thumb to remember is this: your shader means what it says it means. Parameters given to pipeline creation cannot *change* the meaning of your code.

If you intend to have the fragment shader really use [4, 8), then the fragment shader must *really use it:*

```
layout(push_constant) uniform fragmentPushConstants {
    layout(offset = 4) float test2;
} u_pushConstants;
```

Since it has a different definition from the VS version, it should have a different block name too. The `offset` layout specifies the offset of the variable in question. That's standard stuff from GLSL, and [compiling for Vulkan](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/khr/GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl.txt) doesn't change that.

Comment: The spec states that only 128 bytes is guaranteed to be supported for push constants. Assuming such minimal hardware, is that limit for the total size of both push constant structs combined, or are those 128 bytes the size of a window that you can use at one time; in other words, would a `layout(offset = 128) float test2;` always fail on such hardware?

Comment: @CarloWood: The limit is on the size used by `VkPushConstantRange`, which applies to every range you specify: "`size` must be less than or equal to `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::maxPushConstantsSize` minus
`offset`".